# Run on simulator while having SDK that don't show classes on simulator ( prevent me from running)

Tags: ios, swift, sdk

I am using we-accept SDK from  https://www.weaccept.co/ for accepting payment .

My problem is that when i try to run on simulator ( not to use that SDK but for other reason) Xcode doesn't see any variable or classes from that SDK because the rules for this SDK is that it's not working on simulator.

I don't know how to run my application anymore on simulator after using that SDK in my code .

Any help how to run on simulator with my code containing those SDK classes ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must differentiate between Simulator and real when use any of this pod codes :

```
  #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
    // your simulator code
  #else
   // your real device code
  #endif
```